# Using Gson convert Java object into JsonObject

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java object, and I want to output it as a JSON string. BUT I want to avoid printing out a property in the Java object. I know that I could do this using GsonBuilder's excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() method. However, I thought I'd try the alternate approach of removing the property from the JsonObject before printing it out. The following code works:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss").create();
String javaObjectString = gson.toJson(javaObject);
//javaObjectString currently include "property":"value"
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(javaObjectString, javaObject.getClass());
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonElement;
jsonObject.remove("property");
javaObjectString = gson.toJson(jsonObject);
//javaObjectString currently no longer includes "property":"value"
```

However, it feels a but hacky because I have to output the Java object to a String, and then create a JsonElement from the String, and then cast the JsonElement to a JsonObject.

Is there a more direct way to go from a Java object to a JsonObject?

Answer (score 42):

You don't need the intermediary `String`. Serialize your Java object to a `JsonElement` directly with `Gson#toJsonTree(Object)`. Cast that value to whatever type you expect (JSON object, array, or primitive), perform your removal and invoke its `toString()` method to retrieve its JSON representation as a `String`.

For example,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss").create();
// JSON data structure
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(javaObject);
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonElement;
// property removal
jsonObject.remove("property");
// serialization to String
String javaObjectString = jsonObject.toString();
```

---

You can always use the `Gson#toJson` overload that accepts a `JsonElement` to serialize it directly to a stream if you want to skip that last `String` object creation.